# No drilldown from SonarQube Unit Test Success widget

Tags: nunit, sonarqube

We use Jenkins to build C# project, to run unit tests (NUnit) and code coverage (NCover). As output, `coverage.nccov` and `nunit-result.xml` files.

Jenkins triggers SonarQube analysis (SonarQube 5.0.1 and up to date C# plugin). The SonarQube dashboard displays unit tests coverage and unit tests results, but list of failed tests cannot be displayed as drilldown.

[image: widget]

When user clicks on the metrics, the page displayed is quite empty (no list of files, no drilldown, just the metric).

[image: metric detail]

`sonar-project.properties`:

```
sonar.visualstudio.solution=MyProject.sln
sonar.cs.ncover3.reportsPaths=coverage.nccov
sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths=nunit-result.xml
```

Unit Tests Coverage metrics display drilldown as expected.

[image: test coverage drilldown]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This indeed is a known limitation of the plugin, which depends on this ticket:  https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARCS-657

For your information, the main difficulty to implement this feature is due to unit test reports not containing links back to the source code files, but only to assemblies/types/methods instead. SonarQube needs to know which files to show in the drilldown.

Comment: I understand this limitation. Can you tell me why we can't have the list of unit tests, by namespace or assemblies (with no source code)?

Comment: SonarQube is designed to report issues on source files, so it won't gather information that lack source code

Comment: So, until `nunit-results.xml` doesn't contains path to source code file, there is no way to display a drill down for unit tests in SonarQube (for C# projects)?

Comment: until we're not able to do this mapping somehow. adding that information in `nunit-results.xml` would indeed be one way to get that mapping.

Comment: One more issue with C# unit test count: if you going to add javascript tests - c# unit tests not counting anymore @DineshBolkensteyn