# Test success rate not showing in sonar unit test widget for dotnet project

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube, xunit, sonar-runner

I have ran sonar runner for msbuild on a c# dot net project. After running below is the result I got in unit test widget,

[image: overall unit test result]

It doesn't show unit test success rate. While further checking I found that unit test for each file also not showing as below.

[image: unit test result for each file] 
I have followed [Unit Test Execution Results Import (C#, VB.NET)](https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6389772) documentation page while doing this. I have executed below shell commands to run sonar runner

```
SET dotnet="C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe"
SET opencover=C:\Users\lakshmanu\.nuget\packages\opencover\4.6.519\tools\OpenCover.Console.exe 
SET targetargs="test -f netcoreapp2.0 -c Release test/Services/UnitTest/UnitTest.csproj"  
SET filter="+[Test.MyTest.*]* -[*.Test]* -[xunit.*]* -[another]*"  
SET coveragefile=Coverage.xml

dotnet restore %WORKSPACE%\Myproj\My.API

MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:"test" /n:"test" /v:"1" /s:%WORKSPACE%\SonarQube.Analysis.xml /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths="Coverage.xml" /d:sonar.cs.xunit.reportsPaths="D:\sources\test\Services\UnitTest\XUnitResults.xml"

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" Myproj.sln /t:Rebuild

REM Run code coverage analysis  
%opencover% -oldStyle -register:user -target:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe" -targetargs:"test\Services\UnitTest\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\UnitTest.dll /Framework:FrameworkCore10" -filter:%filter% -output:%coveragefile% -skipautoprops -hideskipped:All
cd test\Services\UnitTest\
dotnet xunit -xml XUnitResults.xml
cd ..\..\..

MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end
```

Tests are written using xunit framework. Sonarqube version is 5.6.6.
Any clue on why test success rate or unit test per file is not showing?

**UPDATE**

While googling I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37985440/unit-tests-1-but-beneath-it-the-list-is-empty), according to that and sonarqube documentation number of unit test per each file is not supported at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SonarQube simply doesn't track those metrics.

Theoretically, your unit test success rate should always be 100%. Anything less should fail the build and preempt the analysis.

Comment: That means, is this the expected behavior? Anyway when I have 100% test success case also, test success rate is not showing on unit test widget.

Comment: according to the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117785/no-drilldown-from-sonarqube-unit-test-success-widget, It seems this is possible.